# Jquery start date and end date validation error

Tags: jquery

```
$("#EndDate").change(function () {
    var startDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;
    if ((Date.parse(endDate) <= Date.parse(startDate))) {
        alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
        document.getElementById("EndDate").value = "";
    }
});
```

If I used this logic,
It doesn't work when I pick the date from the datepicker,
If I wrote the date manually in the textbox this logic is working.
Can any one have a fix for this.

Comment: [Take a peek at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: If you're using jQuery Datepicker, use `$(selector).datepicker("getDate")` to get the selected date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.datepicker to get the date.
If you use datepicker to select a date, parsing it as text may not be the best way.

$(selector).datepicker("getDate") will return you an actual time object.

In your case:

```js
if ($("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate") >= $("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate")) {
  alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
  $("#EndDate").val("");
}
```

This is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1qo9be6s/

Comment: $("#addvalidations").click(function () {        
          if ($("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate") >= $("#txtToDate").datepicker("getDate")) {
              alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
              $("#txtToDate").val("");
          }
      });